# Using jquery toggle on individual divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to create a toggle effect using + and - boxes for showing and hiding divs. And example http://theodin.co.uk/tools/tutorials/jqueryTutorial/index.html

This is the script I'm using

```
$(function(){
        $('.block').hide();
            $('#show').toggle(function(){
                    $('.block').show(); 
                    $(this).attr("src","images/minus.jpg" );
            },function(){
                $('.block').hide(); 
                $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.jpg" );
            });
    });
```

The HTML

```
<div id="show"> Open <img id="show" src="images/plus.jpg"/> </div>
    <div class="block"> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    </div>
```

It works fine with one div but I have multiple and when I click one, they all show. Is there a way to toggle them individually using the code I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `show ID` to a `class` like this:

```
<div class="show"> Open <img src="images/plus.jpg" /> </div>
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>  

<div class="show"> Open <img src="images/plus.jpg" /> </div>
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Then the jQuery becomes:

```
$('.show').toggle(function(){
  $(this).next('.block').show(); 
  $(this).children("img").attr("src","images/minus.jpg" );
},function(){
  $(this).next('.block').hide(); 
  $(this).children("img").attr("src", "images/plus.jpg" );
});
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/JRhWY/)

Comment: Thank you! This works!Do you know if jquery allow to hide() the block div if for example one clicks anywhere outside the block or toggles another one?

Comment: btw, I updated teh code with actual image URLs but the images don't change

Comment: My bad. I didn't test with images. We'll use `children("img")` in order to do that. I've updated the example above to reflect it.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! That also solves another issue that made all images change at once.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the `src` of the `#show` element, when you should be changing it on its child `<img>`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').hide();
    $('#show').toggle(function(){
         $('.block').show(); 
         $(this).children('img').attr("src","images/minus.jpg" );
    },function(){
         $('.block').hide(); 
         $(this).children('img').attr("src", "images/plus.jpg" );
    });
});
```

This uses `.children()` to get the child `<img>` element so you can change its source.

Also, the `<img>` has the same ID as its parent. This is not allowed. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Also, the div has and ID of "show", as well as the img. Look, the whole crew's in tonight!

Comment: @karim79 - True. Just finished updating. :o)

Comment: Thank you for the code! I tried it but I had the same issue for some reason. Maybe my HTML is wrong. However the code Gert provided seems to work.

Comment: @user - Yes, there would be trouble if you had multiple identical IDs. That tends to break things.